# Epiphany regex-route error

Tags: php, regex, rest, epiphany

i'm trying to implement a Rest web services using [epiphany framework](https://github.com/jmathai/epiphany) in this way:

```
include_once 'rest/Epi.php';

Epi::setSetting('exceptions', true);
Epi::setPath('base', 'rest');
Epi::init('route');
getRoute()->post('/city/(\w+)', 'getCity');
getRoute()->run();

function getCity($tmp){
    //My work
}
```

The problem borns when i use url like:

```
http://mydomain/*/city/OLOMOUC-REPUBLICA%20CHECA
```

what i understood is that the problem is with regex `(\w+)`, how can i change it to allow any string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the OP wants to match everything. So `(.*)` did the job.

---

`\w` is the same as writing `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Which basically means you should use `([\w\s%-]+)`. `\s` will match a whitespace.

Comment: it works if the string is in the format "string-string". if the string is in the form "string -string" it doesn't work.. i need something that can take every string

Comment: @JackTurky Please be precise. Regex isn't a guess game. You have provided an example where there isn't a space. I will edit the regex for now.

Comment: @JackTurky Oh and if you want to match *everything* then just use `.*`, but I doubt that you want that ...

Answer (score 0):

Try This Regex it will work as url doesnot contain space...

```
/city/(\S+)
```